# Error while Installing Wordnet-3.0 on ubuntu: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions

Tags: installation, tcl, tk-toolkit, ubuntu-14.04, wordnet

I downloaded Wordnet-3.0 and as it says tcl and tk must already be installed.
So I checked this using following:

```
vidyasagar@vidyasagar-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~/Documents/NLP/WordNet-3.0$ dpkg -s tcl
Package: tcl
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: interpreters
Installed-Size: 51
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: tcltk-defaults
Version: 8.6.0+6ubuntu3
Provides: tclsh
Depends: tcl8.6 (>= 8.6.0-2)
Breaks: tcl8.3 (<< 8.3.5-15), tcl8.4 (<< 8.4.20-2), tcl8.5 (<< 8.5.14-3), tcl8.6 8.6.0-2)
Conflicts: tcl-lib, tcl8.5-lib
Description: Tool Command Language (default version) - shell
 Tcl is a powerful, easy to use, embeddable, cross-platform interpreted
scripting language.
This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
 Tcl version (currently 8.6).
Original-Maintainer: Debian Tcl/Tk Packagers <pkg-tcltk-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
vidyasagar@vidyasagar-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~/Documents/NLP/WordNet-3.0$
```

So it seems it is already installed.
Now I checked for tk.

```
vidyasagar@vidyasagar-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~/Documents/NLP/WordNet-3.0$ dpkg -s tk
Package: tk
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: interpreters
Installed-Size: 51
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: tcltk-defaults
Version: 8.6.0+6ubuntu3
Provides: wish
Depends: tk8.6 (>= 8.6.0-2), tcl
Breaks: tk8.3 (<< 8.3.5-16), tk8.4 (<< 8.4.20-2), tk8.5 (<< 8.5.14-3), tk8.6 (<< 8.6.0-2)
Conflicts: tk-lib, tk8.5-lib
Description: Toolkit for Tcl and X11 (default version) - windowing shell
 Tk is a cross-platform graphical toolkit which provides the Motif
look-and-feel and is implemented using the Tcl scripting language.
This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
 Tk version (currently 8.6).
Original-Maintainer: Debian Tcl/Tk Packagers <pkg-tcltk-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
vidyasagar@vidyasagar-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~/Documents/NLP/WordNet-3.0$
```

Now I am in the folder WordNet-3.0 and I run
    ./configure
I am getting error as following:

```
checking for Tcl configuration... configure: WARNING: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions
```

What is the problem...?

Answer (score 9):

It can't find a file (called `tclConfig.sh`) that describes *exactly* how to set up the compiler so as to have access to the Tcl header files and library files in their installation location; the place to find it is given via the `--with-tcl` option to the WordNet `configure` script. There's an equivalent one for Tk (`tkConfig.sh`) too.

I guess that you need the `tcl-dev` and `tk-dev` packages, since you're not just wanting to use Tcl and Tk but write code against the library. (Because that's how Debian-derived distributions like to package things.)